# Num of Sec Since Begining Of Month in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, time

How to get the Number of Seconds Since the Begining Of Month in C++?

i just wanted to know how to think on the alogorithm of such a question

i think i know the right way but i dont have the right tools to solve it

i have tought on this way:

```
                time_t rawtime1, rawtime2;                  //Time type

                struct tm * timeinfo;                       //Time structure

                time(&rawtime1);                            //to Get current time

                time(&rawtime2);                            //to Get current time

                timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime2);            //Convert time_t to tm as local time

                //setting up in rawtime2 to the beggining of this specific month - like a reset to 0 in month and days

                //now will convert rawtime2 to seconds with mktime

                return rawtime1 - rawtime2;
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE !!

Comment: So, to set rawtime2 to the beginning of the month, you have to subtract the right number of seconds from it. How can you determine the right number of seconds to subtract?

Comment: i just set raw2 somehow to the begining of the same month and then convert raw2 with mktime and then subtract: raw1-raw2. is this algorithem is possible? thanks

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the "somehow". How do you get the beginning of the month?

Comment: You don't need mktime. You just need to figure out how to get the number of seconds to subtract.

Comment: If you used mktime, you wouldn't use it on rawtime2. You'd use it on timeinfo. mktime converts a struct tm to a time_t value. It's the opposite of localtime().

Comment: Is there something in timeinfo you could use?

Comment: ok, first setting up two variables: var1, var2, both of them with time since epoch. now convert var2 to local time. then i have this form in var2 "Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy" and i will set "dd" to first day, "HH:MM:SS" to 00:00:00. then convert var2 to time in seconds. then subtract between var1 and var2.

Comment: No, you still have a time_t in var2. You have "Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy" in timeinfo.

Comment: You didn't convert var2 to localtime. You passed it to localtime and got back a struct tm that you put in timeinfo.

Comment: so i will get: time(&rawtime2); timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime2);

Comment: Right. Then something in timeinfo gives you the clues for how to get the time_t value for the beginning of the month.

Comment: How would you get the beginning of the current minute?

Comment: with % ? im tring to get it right

Comment: So in timeinfo, you have the current number of seconds. "www mmm dd hh:mm:SS yyyy". If you subtract that number of seconds from rawtime2 (or rawtime1, either one since they're both the current time), what do you wind up with?

Comment: example: i now have "Wed Feb 13 15:46:00 2013" how it helps me?

Comment: Well, it tells you you're at the beginning of the current minute. Suppose you have "Wed Feb 13 15:46:47 2013". How do you get the time_t for the beginning of the current minute?

Comment: subtract between the seconds to get "SS"--> "00"

Comment: i can use another string that will hold the info and then reset the values from him?

Comment: If you do rawtime2 = rawtime2 - timeinfo->tm_sec, you won't need another variable. Just subtract the seconds from rawtime2.

Comment: i get it now. this line will give me SS to be 00?

Comment: rawtime2 is a time_t, which is just a number, an int. All you can do with it is add or substract seconds. timeinfo is a pointer to a structure, so you can access its members by doing timeinfo->tm_sec, etc.

Comment: So one approach is to subtract seconds from rawtime2 until it's back to the beginning of the minute, or hour, or day, or month. The members in timeinfo give you the numbers you need to do this.

Comment: Another approach would be to take timeinfo and zero out the seconds, minutes, hours, and mdays, and then use mktime() on that to get the time_t for the beginning of the month. Either way will work.

Comment: Tom Barron, thank you very much for all the help. i wasn't online for few hours, and i will give it a try again now

Comment: i think i made it: what do you say: long int numOfSeconds;
 numOfSeconds = 0;
 time_t rawtime1, rawtime2;     //Time type
 struct tm * timeinfo1;      //Time structure
 time(&rawtime1);       //to Get current time
 time(&rawtime2);       //to Get current time
 timeinfo1 = localtime(&rawtime1);   //Convert time_t to tm as local time Www Mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy
 //reset to the start of the month
 timeinfo1->tm_sec = 0;
 timeinfo1->tm_min = 0;
 timeinfo1->tm_hour = 0;
 timeinfo1->tm_mday = 0;
 rawtime1 = mktime(timeinfo1);
 numOfSeconds = rawtime2 - rawtime1;
 _itoa(numOfSeconds, sendBuff, 10);

Comment: Looks like you got! Good job!